# How do I transfer tez while invoking a smart contract using Taquito?

Tags: smart-contracts, taquito

```
const op = await contract.methods
        .buy(contractParams?.height, contractParams?.width)
        .send();
```

I have a `buy` entrypoint and would like to pass in some parameters and some tez at the same time. How should this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to include the amount in the send call

```
const op = await contract.methods
        .buy(contractParams?.height, contractParams?.width)
        .send({ amount: 1});
```

Comment: You can also send `mutez` instead of `tez`, for example, `.send({ amount: 1})` is going to send 1 tez but `.send({ amount: 1000000, mutez: true})` is going to send 1.000.000 mutez.